# how to detect samsung virtual buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I made my app responsive using react native responsive screen and using widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp and using these persentage values to scale across all devices and for most devices that seems to do the trick however when it comes to samsung specific devices that use onscreen buttons eg s8 s9 s10 note series etc it doesn't seem to detect the onscreen buttons and some content ends up being hidden

for example on all the pixel phones the screen height ends at the on screen buttons but when it comes to these samsung devices it seems like it doesn't knew there even there

Answer (score 0):

Each component from my applications has a View that uses a

```
someStyle: {
  flex: 1 
}
```

Some of them do not have that style but their parent does.

Comment: i do not understand your answer

Comment: how does that answer my question

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining it further, what i mean is, instead of trying to calculate the height/width of the device, try to use flex-box alredy provided for react-native on the container of your components.

Comment: that still would not help me because the issue is that react is not detecting that samsung devices have touch buttons which are taking up space on the display